# Testing an SFTP client with Spock Framework

Tags: java, groovy, junit, sftp, spock

We actually use `JUnit` and the great [`FakeSftpServerRule`](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fake-sftp-server-rule) junit rule to test a custom SFTP client we made. That was working great.

Lastly, we want to get rid of junit in favor of the spock framework because we try to migrate to groovy.

Do you guys know any equivalent of `FakeSftpServerRule` or any way to "switch" a junit rule into a spock rule equivalent ?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What stops you from using the same author's [Fake SFTP Server Lambda](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fake-sftp-server-lambda)? BTW, Spock 1.3 can also use JUnit 4 rules, and it might work with the JUnit 4 compatibility layer in Spock 2.x, too. Actually, instead of asking for libraries (which is considered off-topic here and attracts close votes), you ought to post code and ask a concrete question about it, explaining what does not work the way you expect or wish it to.

Comment: Ow! totaly my bad, did not remember this fork !

btw, my CEO wants to delete completely junit because of the incompatibility between versions... it's a nightmare for him... ^^

Comment: @kriegaex could you please create an answer post ? I'll validate it as a good answer, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same author also published [Fake SFTP Server Lambda](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fake-sftp-server-lambda), which is independent of the test framework in contrast to the JUnit 4 rule you use.

If you want to stick with the old tool, Spock 1.3 can also use JUnit 4 rules, and in Spock 2.x it might also work with the JUnit 4 compatibility layer.

---

**Update:** Here is an example program using the SSHJ library for downloading a file from an SFTP server, so we have a subject under test:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71081881;

import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.transport.verification.PromiscuousVerifier;
import net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.InMemoryDestFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SFTPFileDownloader {
  private String host;
  private int port;
  private String user;
  private String password;

  public SFTPFileDownloader(String host, int port, String user, String password) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
  }

  protected static class ByteArrayInMemoryDestFile extends InMemoryDestFile {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public ByteArrayOutputStream getOutputStream() {
      return outputStream;
    }
  }

  public String getFileContent(String path) throws IOException {
    try (
      SSHClient sshClient = setupSshj();
      SFTPClient sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient()
    )
    {
      ByteArrayInMemoryDestFile inMemoryDestFile = new ByteArrayInMemoryDestFile();
      sftpClient.get(path, inMemoryDestFile);
      return inMemoryDestFile.getOutputStream().toString("UTF-8");
    }
  }

  private SSHClient setupSshj() throws IOException {
    SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
    client.connect(host, port);
    client.authPassword(user, password);
    return client;
  }
}
```

The following Spock specification uses the Fake SFTP Server Lambda in two ways:

1. In feature method `"use original server class"`, we use `withSftpServer` the way it was intended by its author, i.e. configuring it and performing interactions in a single lambda or Groovy closure. The only way to make it a bit more spockish is to assign results to previously defined variables and use them in Spock conditions outside of the closure later. Like Leonard said, the resulting Spock specification code is suboptimal, because of the consumer's greed to immediately execute all interactions and close the server again.
2. In feature method `"use custom server class"`, we use a custom `CloseableFakeSftpServer` which shamelessly utilises its parent's private constructors, methods and fields. In a Groovy class, we can do that. But of course, it would be much better for the upstream library to be extended and opened up a little in order to support a more spock-like way to first create and configure the server and later perform interactions and verify results, without being confined to a lambda or closure. I even made the helper class `@AutoCloseable` and use the Spock `@AutoCleanup` extension in order to avoid manual closing in a `cleanup:` block. The helper class also uses Groovy's `@Delegate FakeSftpServer` in order to expose the delegate's methods in its own interface. This is a workaround for not being able to simply extend the original server class, because not even Groovy can call a private super constructor.

So this is the helper class for test variant #2:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71081881

import com.github.stefanbirkner.fakesftpserver.lambda.FakeSftpServer

class CloseableFakeSftpServer implements AutoCloseable {
  @Delegate
  private FakeSftpServer fakeSftpServer
  private Closeable closeServer

  CloseableFakeSftpServer() {
    fakeSftpServer = new FakeSftpServer(FakeSftpServer.createFileSystem())
    closeServer = fakeSftpServer.start(0)
  }

  @Override
  void close() throws Exception {
    fakeSftpServer.fileSystem.close()
    closeServer.close()
  }
}
```

And here we finally have the specification with the two alternative feature methods (I like the second one better):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71081881

import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Specification

import static com.github.stefanbirkner.fakesftpserver.lambda.FakeSftpServer.withSftpServer
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8

class SFTPServerTest extends Specification {
  @AutoCleanup
  def server = new CloseableFakeSftpServer()
  def user = "someone"
  def password = "secret"

  def "use original server class"() {
    given:
    def fileContent = null

    when:
    withSftpServer { server ->
      server.addUser(user, password)
      server.putFile("/directory/file.txt", "content of file", UTF_8)
      // Interact with the subject under test
      def client = new SFTPFileDownloader("localhost", server.port, user, password)
      fileContent = client.getFileContent("/directory/file.txt")
    }

    then:
    fileContent == "content of file"
  }

  def "use custom server class"() {
    given: "a preconfigured fake SFTP server"
    server.addUser(user, password)
    server.putFile("/directory/file.txt", "content of file", UTF_8)

    and: "an SFTP client under test"
    def client = new SFTPFileDownloader("localhost", server.port, user, password)

    expect:
    client.getFileContent("/directory/file.txt") == "content of file"
  }

}
```

[Try it in the Groovy web console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&gist=d28d296cc177a1ea882700c4c0fe0148).

Comment: Looking at the code of lambda it seems to be only partially suited for Spock as you have to write all the interaction in a closure, it can't span across multiple blocks. With some small glue code it could be turned into a Spock extension, that uses and interceptor to make it available to the test.

Comment: I agree. There is no public constructor or factory for a fake SFTP server which can be configured without immediately consuming the consumer lambda and closing the server again. I.e., configuring the server e.g. in `given:`, calling some application code in `when:` and verifying results in `then:` is impossible like this. I am going to update my answer with an example showing how to work around that in a rather ugly and non-spockish way.

Comment: **Update #2:** I was interested in this topic and am now using a more realistic class under test, using another library to perform an SFTP download, not using the fake server itself. I am also showing a little dirty trick with a fake server subclass allowing for spock-style usage, i.e. we can now define, configure, use and clean up the fake SFTP server separately as well as define interactions and verify conditions separately, too. I.e., we can do each of the relevant parts in the Spock blocks we like. There is no more need to use lambdas or closures and do everything at once inside of them.

Comment: **Update #3:** I created a [pull request](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fake-sftp-server-lambda/pull/11) which adds `CloseableFakeSftpServer` directly to the upstream library in a cleaner way, making some base class members `protected` instead of `private` in order to avoid dirty tricks in Spock. You can just check out the PR branch, build a snapshot and try it. Of cours, I cannot guarantee that the maintainer is going to accept the PR.

Comment: This was exactly what I was about to ask for. You guys rocks. 
Maybe all people concerned with this issue and interested in your improvement in the base lib can :thumbup: the pull request ?